# Evernote API: can't sync the contents of a linked notebook on the sandbox server

Tags: evernote

I am currently testing a custom app performing a full sync with the Evernote service. I'm using Evernote's test site `sandbox.evernote.com`. Everything went well until I tried to create a second account on the same testing server in order to share a notebook with my first account in order to test the sync of a linked notebook's contents.

The Evernote API methods I call in order to sync with the linked notebook's contents are as follows:

1. [authenticateToSharedNotebook](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_authenticateToSharedNotebook) - works i.e. returns the authentication token for the notebook, however, the expiration time of the token is just 1 hour ahead. A bit strange but still usable for testing.
2. [getLinkedNotebookSyncState](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getLinkedNotebookSyncState) - also works, returns the valid looking sync state.
3. [getLinkedNotebookSyncChunk](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getLinkedNotebookSyncChunk) - I call it with the linked notebook previously received from syncing the user's content, afterUSN = 0 (since this is the first sync of this linked notebook's contents), max entries = 50 (randomly picked value which works fine with [getFilteredSyncChunk](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getFilteredSyncChunk) method when syncing stuff from user's own account), full sync only = true. The method throws `EDAMUserException` exception which says `PERMISSION_DENIED parameter=authenticationToken`.

As far as I understand, my developer's key is the one of `full` type, not `basic` - I am able to both read and update notes in the sandbox from my app, so it's not the issue of upgrading the key from `basic` to `full`.

If that matters, I am using the unofficial API [implementation](https://github.com/d1vanov/QEverCloud) in C++/Qt, however, it worked like a charm until now and the code it uses is automatically generated right from Thrift IDL files so there are no signs the problem is with the client's API implementation.

I would much appreciate if someone from Evernote could explain why I am receiving this error and how to overcome this so that I can continue testing the sync with linked notebooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I figured out what the problem was:

1. I used the same `NoteStore` object for syncing both user's own content and the content from linked notebooks - that might have been OK if I properly set the note store URL to that object so that it corresponds to the linked notebook I'm trying to sync. I didn't do that. Now I use separate `NoteStore` objects for user's own content and for each linked notebook, each with its own proper note store URL.
2. I used wrong authentication token in the call to `getLinkedNotebookSyncChunk`: I used the token obtained via `authenticateToSharedNotebook` while I should have used the "regular" user's own authentication token.

I changed these two things and now the exception is not thrown, the sync chunk from the linked notebook is downloaded properly.